# Combine custom title with FEATURE_PROGRESS

Tags: android, android-layout, android-titlebar

In my onCreate() I set a progress bar as follows:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
```

Now, wishing to enhance that title bar a little bit, I want to change its [background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2285722/869501) color. First step is to check if `FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE` is supported:

```
final boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
if ( customTitleSupported ) {
    Log.i(TAG, "CUSTOM TITLE SUPPORTED!")
}
```

But as soon as I call that `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE)` I get an:

```
AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
```

*(It doesn't matter if I call this function before setting `FEATURE_PROGRESS` or after)*

Any idea how to [work around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2840407/869501) this?

**Alternatively**, I would avoid a [custom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3438352) title bar, if I could find the non-custom title bar's resource [ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10592561). Something that's better than the dangerous [getParent()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146504).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documentation says](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE):

> FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE
>
> Flag for custom title. You cannot combine this
>   feature with other title features.

What you can do as you mentioned is to use a custom title bar with a ProgressBar, [here is an example how to accomplish that](http://kmansoft.com/2010/09/23/showing-progress-in-standard-window-title-bar/).

In the other hand, why aren't you using Action Bar?.

Comment: Because `ActionBar` is only present in Android 3.0+ and I need to run on 2.x as well.