# findViewById(android.R.id.progress) returns null

Tags: android, android-resources, android-progressbar, android-titlebar

The Android Developers reference lists [R.id.progress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html#progress) among the built-in View resources available.

Yet, when I issue (in my activity class) the statement:

```
View pv = getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.progress);
```

It returns null.

It returns null even when I use it in conjunction with the `ProgressBar` class:

```
ProgressBar pv = (ProgressBar) getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.progress);
```

And it returns null even [without the getWindow()](http://foo.jasonhudgins.com/2010/03/simple-progressbar-tutorial.html):

```
ProgressBar pv = (ProgressBar) findViewById(android.R.id.progress);
```

Any idea why?

To make sure I'm not hallucinating, I followed @Geobits's advice and created a new project from scratch, containing the **exact** code listed in [the blog post](http://foo.jasonhudgins.com/2010/03/simple-progressbar-tutorial.html) recommended by @ArunGeorge below:

```
package com.droidworks;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class ProgressBarExampleActivity extends Activity {
  private ProgressBar mProgress;
  private MyThread mBgThread;
  private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(android.R.id.progress);

    mBgThread = (MyThread) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();

    if (mBgThread == null) {
      mBgThread = new MyThread();
      mBgThread.start();
    }

    mHandler.post(mThreadWatcher);
  }

  @Override
  public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return mBgThread;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mThreadWatcher);
    super.onPause();
  }

  private Runnable mThreadWatcher = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        int progress = mBgThread.getProgress();
        mProgress.setProgress(progress);

        if (progress != 100)
          mHandler.postDelayed(this, 50);
      }
    };

  static class MyThread extends Thread {

    private int _progress = 0;

    public void run() {
      for (; _progress < 100; _progress++) {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
      }
    }

    private int getProgress() {
      return _progress;
    }
  }

}
```

Sure enough, this code throws a `NullPointerException`:

```
at com.droidworks.ProgressBarExampleActivity$1.run(ProgressBarExampleActivity.java:44)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What version of Android?

Comment: because you don't have a view by that ID showing on the screen.

Comment: @user1260028 Froyo (2.2) @Tim What do you mean by "not showing"? Does it have to be visible at the time of that `findViewById()` call?

Comment: Visibility does not affect that. I think Tim just wanted to say that this view is simply not there. Don't you have to request the progress bar as a window feature first? And then it is unlikely that you can find it in onCreate, because layouting didn't happen, yet. You could add an OnGlobalLayoutListener for the right moment. Or maybe just post a delayed method on the UI thread for finding that view

Comment: @NobuGames I can confirm that visibility does not affect that as I just tested it with the progress bar visible. I am issuing that `findViewById()` long after the entire UI has been inflated (**not** in `onCreate()`). So there must be another reason.

Comment: Post some more code from prior to that call. One line doesn't tell the whole story here.

Comment: @Geobits See update in my original post. +1.

Answer (score 1):

The `R.id.progress` built-in tag is designed for the `ProgressBar` class.  If you do not have a `ProgressBar` object or a `ProgressBar` in your XML, then it will return null.

Comment: @ack57 I can see the `ProgressBar` with my eyes... It's true, though, that there isn't any in my XML. It's the system's built-in ProgressBar. Isn't that the entire purpose of those `android.R.id` resources? They *don't* need to be in my XML.

Comment: No, you must have a programmatical connection to the ProgressBar.  Simply entering `R.id.progress` will not fetch the most convenient ProgressBar for you.

Comment: What is "*programmatical connection to the ProgressBar*"?

Comment: A better way to word that is [Scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29).  The progress bar you see does not have global fields ready for you to use.

Comment: OK thanks. So why does it work for [this blogger](http://foo.jasonhudgins.com/2010/03/simple-progressbar-tutorial.html) and the **same exact** code doesn't work for me? (see update above).

Comment: Either he never compiled that, or he had an xml file that he did not post.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

Sorry, I must have counted it up wrong. that's what I get for not pasting. Either way, is there a reason you don't just use one of `ProgressBar`'s [constructors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#ProgressBar%28android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int%29)? Here's the line from the latest project I used a bar in:

```
mProgress = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
```

Comment: The code posted is an exact copy & paste from my own `ProgressBarExampleActivity.java` class producing that exception. The null pointer exception is generated at line 44: `mProgress.setProgress(progress);`. The null is for mProgress. Same problem... Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: To verify that, I check for `if (mProgress == null)` right after the `findViewById()` in onCreate() and issue an error message in LogCat. It's null. I *am* looking at the right place. Feel free to copy this code verbatim and try it on your system. In eclipse it only takes 2 minutes to create a new project from scratch containing the same exact code.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Yes, there is a reason why I'm not using a constructor or even an XML layout: I want the access the **same exact** ProgressBar that's displayed by default by the system on the **TitleBar** - [without](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254366/combine-custom-title-with-feature-progress) using a FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE that is. In other words, I want to access the **same exact** ProgressBar that's accessed by `Activity.setProgress()`. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Oh, didn't know it was going in a title bar. In that case, you might want to check out this: http://pilhuhn.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-and-title-bar-progress.html . Two things of note: The order of calls here is important, and I think you're looking for the `android:attr/progressBarStyleSmallTitle`. You can still set it in XML either way.

Comment: Yup. the link you provided points to a FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE implementation, which isn't what I want because, by design, Android [does not allow combining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254366/combine-custom-title-with-feature-progress) FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE with other features (which I need). Back to square one. :-(

Comment: Right. Maybe I'm just confused. I thought the only reason you couldn't use FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE as because it didn't allow a progressbar with it. The link shows how to use both, using the default title progress bar theme(which you could customize in xml). The key is not requesting FEATURE_PROGRESS because the bar is in the custom title layout. If there's another reason you don't want FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, I could understand, but you -can- do both with the method shown, as it's the whole point of the post.

Answer (score -1):

`android.R.id.progress` is used in conjunction with the `ProgressBar`.

Check this link: http://foo.jasonhudgins.com/2010/03/simple-progressbar-tutorial.html

your usage is thus wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "your usage is thus wrong"? It returns null even when I use the `ProgressBar` class: `ProgressBar pv = (ProgressBar) getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.progress);`. Please explain.

Comment: why don't you simply use `findViewById(android.R.id.progress)` without appending it with the `getWindow()` method?

Answer (score -1):

From Eclipse, perform a project clean by clicking on 'Project' > 'Clean...', click on the checkbox beside your project, and click 'Ok'. And try building your project again.