# findViewById(android.R.id.statusBarBackground) and findViewById(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground) return null?

Tags: android, view, statusbar, navigationbar, findviewbyid

I've tried on `Nougat` and `Oreo`. Both phones are stock android and both views are visible and on screen. I require these views for my `sharedElementTransition`. This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158795/findviewbyidandroid-r-id-statusbarbackground-returns-null) but with no answer. This is happening to a lot of people and they discuss it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600263/how-do-i-prevent-the-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-from-animating-during-an-acti) in the comments of Alex Lockwood's answer, but with no definite solution.

I am calling `findViewById()` from my activity and have tried both

```
findViewById(android.R.id.statusBarBackground);
```

and

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.statusBarBackground);
```

I've called the `findViewById()` after `setContentView()`

[Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299773/findviewbyidandroid-r-id-progress-returns-null?rq=1), but unlike `progressBar`, `statusBar` and `navigationBar` views do exist almost all the time.

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
        getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(getTransitionSet());
        getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(getTransitionSet());
        getWindow().setSharedElementReturnTransition(getTransitionSet());
        getWindow().setSharedElementReenterTransition(getTransitionSet());
        ActivityCompat.postponeEnterTransition(this);
        setEnterSharedElementCallback(mCallback);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.summary_image_preview);
    navigationBar = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground);
    statusBar = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.statusBarBackground);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    // etc...

}
```

`Toolbar` is a normal view inside my content view and it works fine. but `statusBar` and `navigationBar are null`

Comment: Can you please post more of the code, so we can analyse it and try to locate the error? It's hard to tell you what the problem might be without looking at the code.

Comment: Updated with code. There's not much to It other than what I've said.

Answer (score 0):

The `Views` return null in `onCreate()` function. I checked the same `Views` inside my `Fragment`'s `onViewCreated()` and they were not null. I fixed the issue by delaying `findViewById()` until the point where I needed it.

For some reasor, while other views are available in `onCreate()`, the Views outside your application are only accessible after `Fragment View` creation