# ClassCastException: ActionBarView cannot be cast to TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, textview, classcastexception

I have been using the following workaround to center the activity label (without having to resort to a custom title in XML layout):

```
((TextView)((FrameLayout)((LinearLayout)((ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView()).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

This works great but every once in a while I see one of the users (on Google Play) getting a

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.TextView

These are probably tablet users who are running Android 3.x or higher.

Short of implementing my own custom title that would give me direct access to the activity label, can you recommend another way to avoid that `ActionBarView` to `TextView` ClassCastException?

Perhaps check for the Android version under which the app currently runs and go though another level of `getChildAt(0)`?

Comment: So both the answers are "right" :) Pick one and I can stop wincing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action bar is defined in the theme. So if you want to avoid that ever showing up you need to pick different theme.

Alternatively you can detect what version of OS the user is using and in the case of being 11 (Honeycomb) and higher simply skip the action bar and get the next view.

Which would look something like

```
if (Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) > 11)
{
    ((TextView)((FrameLayout)((LinearLayout)((ViewGroup).getWindow().getDecorView()).getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
else
   ((TextView)((FrameLayout)((LinearLayout)((ViewGroup).getWindow().getDecorView()).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

I would also like to add like Shark said, this is a total hack and is not very robust code.  You should be using findViewById() to locate your views and avoid all of that super ugly casting. You can expect your hack or even the code I just put in to break in the future if you continue down that path.

Answer (score 1):

```
((FrameLayout)((LinearLayout)((ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView()).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)
```

Start collecting child views from here, and search for your own TextView... You just need to skip the actionbar, no need to be nice about it when you started off with a hack anyway.

Comment: Yeah it kind of pained me just pasting that in there, but who am I to judge :)

Comment: it's a terrible terrible workaround but hey, if it works... :) Should I even ask why findViewByID(R.whatever) doesn't work? :) or maybe attach a Tag to your particular textview and run thru all the views until you get it.

Comment: @Roloc LOL I got the hint. I have no idea why I am so afraid of a custom title... +1 to you both.

Comment: Just bear in mind that 1) always use getApplicationContext() and 2) you shouldn't generally store view references in global vars as they leak but I am yet to see why this practice is supposedly bad.

Comment: @Shark OK now I recall why I was trying to get away from a custom title: It cannot be combined with certain features such as FEATURE_PROGRESS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254366/combine-custom-title-with-feature-progress

this was the first hit when I googled "FEATURE_PROGRESS" actually.

Comment: @Shark Yup. I found that one through Google, too. But it has no answers.

Comment: It has very useful links however, with questions simialar to yours with accepted answers... try digging thru those. My work(shift) here is done :)

Comment: @Shark Actually I don't need a progress bar in my app, so I may as well take your recommendation. I will try to follow [this 4.x sample code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/example/android/apis/app/CustomTitle.java) or [this 2.2 one](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.2_r1.1/com/example/android/apis/app/CustomTitle.java).

Comment: Glad to have helped out :) Take care.